# Convert Stream<Item = Result<Vec<T>, _>> to Stream<Item = Result<T>>

Tags: rust, rust-futures

Suppose I have a stream of Result<Vec>:

```rust
let v = Ok(vec![(), ()]);
let s = stream::once(future::ready(v));
```

How can I make `s` be the return value of a function with return type `impl Stream<Item = Result<(), _>`?

Answer (score 3):

The best solution I have is to use `flat_map`, pattern match the `Result`, and `boxed` the streams.

```rust
fn units() -> impl TryStream<Ok = (), Error = ()> {
  let v = Ok(vec![(), ()]);
  let s = stream::once(future::ready(v));
  s.flat_map(|x: Result<Vec<_>, _>| match x {
      Ok(x) => stream::iter(x).map(|x| Ok(x)).boxed(),
      Err(x) => stream::once(future::ready(Err(x))).boxed(),
  })
}
```

Edit:
[See Jeff Garrett's comment for a non boxed solution.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68869642/convert-streamitem-resultvect-to-streamitem-resultt/68869833?noredirect=1#comment121725505_68869833)

Comment: s.map_ok(|x| stream::iter(x.into_iter().map(Ok))).try_flatten() ?

Comment: @JeffGarrett That works. Thanks! [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=202f835791552d6d4ac2ba3145fe4669)